# How to check an radio box without id in python

Tags: python, selenium, button

I'm making a code that clicks a few buttons on a site with python and selenium. For most of the buttons I could use the class or ID to click it but with the radio box it doesn't work. I've watched several tutorial but none of them worked. Can someone help me? The part of the code I want to click is this:

```
<div class="paycontainer"><div class="payselect" onclick="wishlist_klantinfo(&quot;&quot;, {action:&quot;update&quot;,id:&quot;betaaltype_payid&quot;,val:18})">  <input type="radio" name="betaalmethode" value="18"></div><div class="paylogo" onclick="wishlist_klantinfo(&quot;&quot;, {action:&quot;update&quot;,id:&quot;betaaltype_payid&quot;,val:18})">  <img src="/templates/basic/images/pay/pay_18.png"></div><div class="paytitle" onclick="wishlist_klantinfo(&quot;&quot;, {action:&quot;update&quot;,id:&quot;betaaltype_payid&quot;,val:18})">  PayPal <br>(1.5%)</div><div class="payextrafields wl_hidden"></div></div>
```

Comment: Share relevant HTML and code that you have tried and errorStackTrace if any

Comment: Try to use xpath instead of id

Comment: @YevheniiChykalov : Can you explain why would anyone prefer xpath over ID ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It's just a matter of taste. Sometimes XPATH helps if DOM elements contain dynamic attribute values.

Comment: i've tried a couple of manners such as: WebElement radio1 = driver.findElement(By.id("betaaltype_payid")) but this didn't work also i've tried to change the value to the right box but I don't think this is the way to check it. Sorry i'm new to python so maybe asking a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple elements in that HTML sample, which one do you want to click?

**payselect**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='payselect']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.payselect').click()
```

**paylogo**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='paylogo']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.paylogo').click()
```

**paytitle**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='paytitle']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.paytitle').click()
```

Comment: the thing is that these variables are multiple times on the website so it gives an error. The only thing that's different is the value of the radio box